# How to solve the error "Automation error" without any apparent cause?

Tags: excel, vba, selenium-webdriver

Actually, I've been trying to create automation with VBA. For now, it just needs to open Microsoft Edge. I've done everything correctly, including installing the Edge driver and replacing the old one with the new version. I selected the right version to install, matching my Edge version.

However, when I decided to run, it returned an "automation error." I've already tried everything I can to solve it, but the same error keeps occurring. I even tried deleting the Edge driver to see if it would return a different error message, but it didn't. I've researched a lot in different places and forums, I'm still stuck at the same step.

Maybe Important Information:

- I´m using Office 365
- The operational system version is 64x
- The Edge webdriver version and the Edge version are the same
- I´m creating this code in my job´s machine

```
Option Explicit

Sub init
    Dim driver as New Selenium.EdgeDriver
        
        driver.Get "about:blank"

End Sub
```

I tried:

- Run it in my personal computer and in my uncle´s computer and it actually worked
- Reinstall everything include the driver and make all the steps
- Deleted others things like some essential files from the selenium folder to verify if it return me another error
- Use and adapt some example code from Selenium to run on Edge (I did this on my personal computer and worked)